# Click through a div and interact with elements behind it (mouse-events: none dosen't work)

Tags: html, css

Actually doing a web oriented project and I'm facing an issue. I have a div containing my chat boxes at the bottom of my screen. This transparent div fills around half of my page, and so covers some elements (buttons and such). I am trying to find a way to click through this transparent div to reach the elements behind it. Problem is, the `mouse-events-none;` doesn't do the trick. For my display I am using a flex-box (`display: flex; flex-direction: row;`)

```html
<template>
    <div id="chat-container">
        <!-- <p> this will be the Chat component </p> -->
        <div id="chat-tabs">
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Epsilon</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Delta</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Omega</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Pi</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Beta</p>
                <div class="under-chat">
                    <ul class="chat">
                        <li class="message">Hello there ! </li>
                        <li class="message">General Kenobi ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I am the negociator ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                        <li class="message">I can see this ! </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>Gamma</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-tab retracted">
                <p class="header" onclick='this.parentNode.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");this.parentNode.classList.toggle("retracted");'>#public</p>
                <div class="under-chat hidden">
                    <ul class="chat">
                    </ul>
                    <input class="chat-input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```css
#chat-container > * {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

#chat-tabs {
    border: solid 3px magenta;

    background-color: rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.2);

    height: 50vh;

    max-width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    overflow-x: scroll;


    z-index: -1;

}

.chat-tab {
    background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-height: 410px;
    bottom: 0;

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    display: block;

    pointer-events: auto;

    z-index: 1;
}

.header {
    background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.header:hover {
    background-color: rgba(00, 00, 00, 1);;
}

.under-chat {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.chat {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style-type:none;


    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 310px;
}

.message {
    background-color:rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8);
    border: solid 1px grey;
    margin:2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: white;
}

.chat-input {
    width: 180px;
    height: 25px;
    padding:10px;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.retracted {
    height: 50px;
}
```

[image]
The pink div symbolize the transparent div I want to click through. Here the "2 factor authentification" is unreachable
If anyone has any insight onto how to solve this problem it would be a great help !

Comment: Did you tried using z-index ?

Comment: I see nowhere `pointer-events:none` set in your css. ?

Comment: @Sanmeet I have tried to use the z-index (setting the containers index to a negative value and setting the chat boxes value to a positive number but it still wouldn't work)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it has been removed during my numerous attempts to make something work

Comment: You need it to click through.  Then it needs to be reset where you need it for children.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean @G-Cyrillus

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/0f52v9op/

Comment: the jsfiddle does work but on my side the pointer-events: none; doesn't work. I can not interact with the chat boxes anymore and I can't click through the div to reach what is behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this in your css code:

```
.chat{
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style-type:none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 310px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

This will make this element appear behind all others, so it will be visible, but it will be behind them. Otherwise, a better approach would be to change the order in which your elements are arranged. It is not at all a good idea for the div to cover the whole page when it needs to just be over the chatbox

Comment: the div must be this size to contain the chat boxes so the height is fixed and the width is auto.
Also setting the z-index doesn't work.